# parsing a filter condition with regular expressions

Tags: regex, scala, regex-greedy

I'm trying to parse a simple filter condition using regular expressions

The filter should have the following syntax:

```
field=value
field:value
field!=value
field<>value
etc... (you get the idea)
```

I came up with the following (in scala)

```
val FilterEntry = """^(\w+)(!?)(=|:|<=|>=|<>|<|>)(.*)$""".r
val FilterEntry(v1, v2, v3, v4) = "field!<>value"
v1: String = field
v2: String = !
v3: String = <>
v4: String = value
```

So it's a fine start

Now I'd like the regular expression to catch (raise an error) when no value is passed

I tried with this (I made the last group non optional)

```
val FilterEntry = """^(\w+)(!?)(=|:|<=|>=|<>|<|>)(.+)$""".r
val FilterEntry(v1, v2, v3, v4) = "field!<>"
v1: String = field
v2: String = !
v3: String = <
v4: String = >
```

So the problem is that it recognizes the operator as "<" and th value as ">" instead of correctly recognizing the operator as "<>" and the value as "" (If I test it with the firest reg exp, it correctly recognizes the operator as <> and the value as "")

I guess I should tell the regular expression to match the operator greedily, but I thought it was like that by default...

-- edit

I've just found this scala console online, for you the test the regular expression
http://www.simplyscala.com/

--

Comment: The are greedy, yes, but that does not mean they may not back track. You need a possessive quantifier for that. I'm still thinking on how you could apply that bit of info on your regexp though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are greedy, yes, but that does not mean they may not back track. You need a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) for that.

Try this one: `^(\w+)(!?)(=|:|<=|>=|<>|<|>){1}+(.+)$`

Note that the order of the alternations in the operators start to matter... If the `<` alternative appears before `<=` and `<>` then the match engine will always greedily match `<` first and then not even attempt to match the longer `<=` or `<>` options. If you just sort your alternatives by length from longest to shortest you should never have this problem.

Comment: yes, I've already realized about the order of the operators, thanks for the tip!

Comment: nice try. but it didn't work, try copy pasting the followgin code in http://www.simplyscala.com/


val FilterEntry = """^(\w+)(!?)(=|:|<=|>=|<>|<|>){1}(.+)$""".r
val FilterEntry(v1, v2, v3, v4) = "field!<>"

Comment: @opensas - I tried the code and it works correctly. You should look at the link in the answer explaining what the _possessive quantifier_ is and how it works. Like owlstead already pointed out, the code in your comment only has `{1}`, which is a _greedy quantifier_. You need to add the `+` on the end to get the _possessive quantifier_ `{1}+`.